# Mapping a json file to excel with python

Tags: json, python-2.7, xls

I would like to take a json format file and map it into an xls file. 
i.e. in the input file

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "promo_video": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/Tztev0Q-CN8?ps=play&vq=large&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1",
      "iap": true,
      "downloads": "10,000,000"
    }
  ]
}
```

to be presented in an excel file: 
column headers: promo video| iap | downloads
and the respective values of each column

Would be helpful to know a recommended way and syntax example.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the specific difficulty that you're facing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `pandas` module along with an excel writer engine module such as `xlwt` or `xlsxwriter` for mapping `json` to `XLS` file. For example

If your `json` is

```
[
   {"key_1":"foo1","key_2":"bar1","key_3":"foobar1"},
   {"key_1":"foo2","key_2":"bar2","key_3":"foobar2"}
]
```

To convert this `json` into `XLS` file

```
import pandas as pd
json_text = """
[
   {"key_1":"foo1","key_2":"bar1","key_3":"foobar1"},
   {"key_1":"foo2","key_2":"bar2","key_3":"foobar2"}
]
"""
df = pd.read_json(json_text)
df.to_excel('output.xls', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you Abinash, that answers well my question.

Answer (score 1):

use `pandas` to convert json file to excel file.

```
import pandas
pandas.read_json("input.json").to_excel("output.xlsx")
```