# Convert Nested JSON to Excel using Python

Tags: python, json, excel

I want to convert Nested JSON to Excel file format using Python. I've done nearly as per requirements but I want to achieve excel format as below.

**JSON**

```js
[
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Cooktops/zgbs/appliances/3741261",
    "subCategory": [
      
    ],
    "title": "Cooktops"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Dishwashers/zgbs/appliances/3741271",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Built-Dishwashers/zgbs/appliances/3741281",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Built-In Dishwashers"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Portable-Countertop-Dishwashers/zgbs/appliances/3741301",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Portable & Countertop Dishwashers"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Dishwashers"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Freezers/zgbs/appliances/3741331",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Chest-Freezers/zgbs/appliances/3741341",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Chest Freezers"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Upright-Freezers/zgbs/appliances/3741351",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Upright Freezers"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Freezers"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Ice-Makers/zgbs/appliances/2399939011",
    "subCategory": [
      
    ],
    "title": "Ice Makers"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Range-Hoods/zgbs/appliances/3741441",
    "subCategory": [
      
    ],
    "title": "Range Hoods"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Ranges/zgbs/appliances/3741411",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Drop-Ranges/zgbs/appliances/3741421",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Drop-In Ranges"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Freestanding-Ranges/zgbs/appliances/3741431",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Freestanding Ranges"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Slide-Ranges/zgbs/appliances/2399946011",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Slide-In Ranges"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Ranges"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Refrigerators/zgbs/appliances/3741361",
    "subCategory": [
      
    ],
    "title": "Refrigerators"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Wall-Ovens/zgbs/appliances/3741481",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Combination-Microwave-Wall-Ovens/zgbs/appliances/3741491",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Combination Microwave & Wall Ovens"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Double-Wall-Ovens/zgbs/appliances/3741501",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Double Wall Ovens"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Single-Wall-Ovens/zgbs/appliances/3741511",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Single Wall Ovens"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Wall Ovens"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Warming-Drawers/zgbs/appliances/2399955011",
    "subCategory": [
      
    ],
    "title": "Warming Drawers"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Washers-Dryers/zgbs/appliances/2383576011",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Clothes-Dryers/zgbs/appliances/13397481",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Dryers"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Clothes-Washing-Machines/zgbs/appliances/13397491",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Washers"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Combination-Washers-Dryers/zgbs/appliances/13755271",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "All-in-One Combination Washers & Dryers"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Stacked-Washer-Dryer-Units/zgbs/appliances/2399957011",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Stacked Washer & Dryer Units"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Washers & Dryers"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Wine-Cellars/zgbs/appliances/3741521",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Built-Wine-Cellars/zgbs/appliances/3741551",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Built-In Wine Cellars"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Freestanding-Wine-Cellars/zgbs/appliances/3741541",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Freestanding Wine Cellars"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Furniture-Style-Wine-Cellars/zgbs/appliances/3741561",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Furniture-Style Wine Cellars"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Small-Wine-Cellars/zgbs/appliances/3741531",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Small Wine Cellars"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Wine-Cellar-Cooling-Systems/zgbs/appliances/3741581",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Wine Cellar Cooling Systems"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Wine-Rooms/zgbs/appliances/3741571",
        "subCategory": [
          
        ],
        "title": "Wine Rooms"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Wine Cellars"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances-Home-Appliance-Warranties/zgbs/appliances/2242350011",
    "subCategory": [
      
    ],
    "title": "Appliance Warranties"
  }
]
```

I'm traversing all subCategories like this:

```
row = 1

def TraverseJSONTree(jsonObject, count=0):
    title = jsonObject.get('title')
    url = jsonObject.get('url')

    print 'Title: ' + title + ' , Position: ' + str(count)

    worksheet.write_string(row, count, title)
    worksheet.write_string(row, 6, url)
    global row
    row+=1 

    subCategories =  jsonObject.get('subCategory',[])

    for category in subCategories:
        TraverseJSONTree(category, count+1)


for jsonObject in json.loads(jsonArray):
    TraverseJSONTree(jsonObject)
```

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

Comment: It will be easy with [pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196668/mapping-a-json-file-to-excel-with-python)

Comment: Can you tell me how to? I've managed to do nearly as per requirement. I'm newbie in Python

Answer (score 2):

Modification :
Simplest way to do this would be to use csv module, say we have the whole json in the variable a

```
import csv
import cPickle as pickle 

fieldnames = ['Category1', 'Category1.1', 'url']
csvfile = open("category.csv", 'wb')
csvfilewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
csvfilewriter.writeheader()

for b in a:     
    data = []
    data.append(b['title'])
    data.append("")
    data.append(b['url'])
    csvfilewriter.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames,data)))
    data = []
    for i in xrange(len(b['subCategory'])):
        data.append(b['title'])
        data.append(b['subCategory'][i]['title'])
        data.append(b['subCategory'][i]['url'])
        csvfilewriter.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames,data)))
```

You will have the desired csv in the same location. This works for only two subcategories (because i have checked the data given by you and say there were only two categories (ie 1 and 1.1)) but in case you want for more than repeat the same(I know it's not the most efficient way couldn't think of any in such a short time)

You can also use pandas module to convert the dictionary
    import pandas as pd
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dcitionaty_element)

And then do it on all the dictionaries in that json and merge them and save it to a csv file.

Comment: can this would work if there are subCategories of subCategories?

Comment: if you know what are max no of sub categories, the i can do that just  need to use the for loop again.

Comment: Python 3 hint: `csvfile = open("category.csv", 'w')`

Answer (score 2):

```
row = 1

def TraverseJSONTree(jsonObject, main_title=None, count=0):
    if main_title is None:
        main_title = title = jsonObject.get('title')
    else:
        title = jsonObject.get('title')
    url = jsonObject.get('url')

    print 'Title: ' + title + ' , Position: ' + str(count)

    if main_title is not None:
        worksheet.write_string(row, 0, title)
    worksheet.write_string(row, count, title)
    worksheet.write_string(row, 6, url)
    global row
    row+=1 

    subCategories =  jsonObject.get('subCategory',[])

    for category in subCategories:
        TraverseJSONTree(category, main_title, count+1)

for jsonObject in json.loads(jsonArray):
    TraverseJSONTree(jsonObject)
```

it will return your expected output as it needs a check if category is there then you have to right the original title on the 0th col in excel reamin as same.

Comment: It's not giving the desired output as mentioned above. I've checked your script and it's give me this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BBlXNiCqn-Z19cCsK_kzpS4fpy4Rknek2ubyvEj4c5E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: All i need should be like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TT5alzmW9tMSR1sOFoi1YgYz_IwnTGUvhh1esHhk8QM/edit?usp=sharing

and it should work if there are more sub categories of sub categories.

Comment: Ahh silly mistake just update title with main_title in following line :if main_title is not None:
        worksheet.write_string(row, 0, main_title)

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine if there is only one subcategory. How can i make it worked if there are multiple sub to sub categories?